Text files, how to write, delete and update lines in a text file
I am writing a small discord bot for me and my friends but I have gotten carried away with it's feautres and right now am trying to create commands that will allow the user to ask to look at a "bank" and it will respond with the total in the bank. i can easily take away the string from the txt file and split it to my needs but my only issue is deleting the line and then after trying to add on. for context, the txt file will normally say "[party name] bank total: [total of moneyz]"
@commands.command()
    async def bankadd(self, ctx, party, total):
        total = int(total)
        party = str(party)
        if party == "help":
            await ctx.send("the parties that have banks open are: [parties here]")
            await ctx.send("please select one of these parties")
        elif party == "[partyName]":
            IB = open("INBank.txt","r")
            i = IB.read()
            d = i.split(" ")
            num = d[3]
            num = int(num)
            IB.close()
            newTotal = total + num

I have tried to do some research on my own but I have been going in circles and I am not certain on how to use the functions in future, so rather than just an explanation on the solution, I want to know how I can use that solution and more bits of information that are grinded down for my brain to process and understand.

The usual approach for small text files like this is to read the entire file, make the changes, add or delete rows, then write the entire file to disk again. You will need to protect against concurrent updates. Some simple form of file locking is usually good enough.

You can use the aiofiles library for asynchronous file reading and writing. Otherwise your bot will stop until the file is read/written/closed/opened. Aiofiles library also provides a thread pool for file processes so it is reliable when you have multiple people using the same command to edit the file.
def update_party_data(file_lines, party_name, new_value):
    edited_file_lines = file_lines
    for i,line in enumerate(file_lines): #Get the line with index
        if line.startswith(party_name):
            index = i
            selected_line = line.rstrip("\n") #Remove newline character
            break
    info = selected_line.split("|")
    info[2] = str(new_value)
    edited_file_lines[index] = "|".join(info) + "\n"
    return edited_file_lines

def get_parties_from_file_content(file_lines):
    #We will perform some formatting here to extract information
    parties = {}
    for line in file_lines:
        info = line.split("|")
        party_name = str(info[0])
        money = int(info[2])
        parties[party_name] = money
    return parties

@commands.command()
async def bankadd(self, ctx, party, total=0):
    total = int(total)
    party = str(party)

    async with aiofiles.open('INBank.txt', mode='r') as f:
        file_lines = await f.readlines()

    all_parties = get_parties_from_file_content(file_lines)

    if party == "help":
        await ctx.send(f"The parties that have banks open are:\n {list(all_parties.keys())}")
        await ctx.send("Please select one of these parties.")
    else:
        print(all_parties)
        party_balance = all_parties[party]
        file_lines = update_party_data(file_lines,party,party_balance+total)
        async with aiofiles.open('INBank.txt', mode='w') as f:
            await f.writelines(file_lines)

I used the '|' pipe character to seperate information. This allows us to use spaces between party names. When inputting spaced party names to bot just use quotes around arguments. The text file should look something like this:
the bulls|Balance|204
second party|Balance|237
my party|Balance|10

Use import aiofiles to import it.

so would it be best to do it from the same txt file or would doing it from separate files be fine? I had a few ideas to make the files hold other data as the bot is for help in Dungeons and Dragons so holding data that each party can access whenever would be useful.
Reason I say this is because I want to make sure I understand this fully before using it, as it is one thing to write the code but then another thing to understand the code.

Seperate files for seperate info is the way to go. Decreases the risk of too many operation on the file at once. Also if the answer was what you are looking for consider accepting it. Thank you in advance.
